# How to generate a random value and its result from a list?

Tags: javascript, random

What I want is, generate a random value displayed in a h tag, and also, display the good value relative to the random one, in an other tag.

```
var first = ['1+2', '10+20', '100+200'];
var second = ['3', '30', '300'];

var first_value = first[Math.floor(Math.random()*first.length)];
var second_value = second[Math.floor(Math.random()*second.length)];

document.getElementById('first_value').innerHTML = first_value;
document.getElementById('second_value').innerHTML = second_value;
```

At the moment, everything is generated randomly, there is no relation between the 2 values generated.

If "10+20" is randomly selected, I want to display "30" in the second html tag.

Comment: Then why do you generate a second random value? Generate one random number only and use it as index for both arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your help my friends, one last question, what's the best solution to not display twice in a row the same random value?

Answer (score 4):

Just store the the random index for both arrays.

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * first.length); // assuming same length

document.getElementById('first_value').innerHTML = first[index];
document.getElementById('second_value').innerHTML = second[index];
```

Another approach is to store values of the same group in an array, and keep the logical group together, instead of using two different arrays.

```
var data = [
        ['1+2', 3],
        ['10+20', 30],
        ['100+200', '300']
    ];
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);

document.getElementById('first_value').innerHTML = data[index][0];
document.getElementById('second_value').innerHTML = data[index][1];
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your help, I will sleep less stupid tonight :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not only get a random number for the first array like below.

```
var first = ['1+2', '10+20', '100+200'];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * first.length);
```

And then with the result you get, calculate the actual outcome with the evaluation method like below

```
document.getElementById('first_value').innerHTML = eval(first[index])
```

Then you don't need the second array

And if the first value is the sum, and the second value the outcome, you could do this:

```
document.getElementById('first_value').innerHTML = first[index]
document.getElementById('second_value').innerHTML = eval(first[index])
```

Comment: Nice, in my case I'm not sure to use figures so, I won't use it but that works for this example, definitely :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generate one random number only and use it as index for both arrays. 
There's no need to generate a second random value. Both arrays just need to be the same length.

```js
var first = ['1+2', '10+20', '100+200'];
var second = ['3', '30', '300'];

var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*first.length);
var first_value = first[index];
var second_value = second[index];

document.getElementById('first_value').innerHTML = first_value;
document.getElementById('second_value').innerHTML = second_value;
```

```html
<div id="first_value"></div>
<div id="second_value"></div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly!